# Writing all model properties into view without having to do it per property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page for listing items, and I have anchors in each of the items to edit it.

So when I click on the edit link, it will take me to the edit page, which have save button and cancel button.

I want it when I click the save button it'll take me to confirmation page which have OK and cancel button.

I know in asp.net mvc you can send model into the view by this

```
return View("Edit", model);
```

It is sensible to then write each of the model property like this in the view

```
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.name )
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.description )
//more properties here...
```

So that after I click the save button, I can have the model back in the controller

But after the edit page, I only need to view a question in the confirmation page do I have to write it manually like this

```
@Html.HiddenFor( model => model.name )
@Html.HiddenFor( model => model.description )
//more properties here...
```

Is there a one line hassle free function to do this in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Html.EditorForModel()` helper. However this method will produce default UI elements like textboxes. You can provide a custom template that will produce hidden inputs.